# How to stop error 'Cannot read property 'gender' of null'?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

This is a problem I keep running into when using data from database in React

> Cannot read property '...' of null'

Up until now I've fixed it by wrapping elements in `if` statements, stopping the function from running if property is null but when I do this.

```
if (healthData !== null) {
    {
        healthData.gender === 'female' ?
            BMRset(655.1 + (9.563 * healthData.weight) + (1.850 * healthData.height) - (4.676 * healthData.age))
            :
            BMRset(88.2 + (13.362 * healthData.weight) + (4.799 * healthData.height) - (5.677 * healthData.age))
    }
}
```

It returns an error of rendered to many times. I'm confused where I can store these calculations?

```
const [healthData, healthDataSet] = useState(null)
const [BMI, BMIset] = useState(null)
const [BMR, BMRset] = useState(null)

const [mealOne_box, mealOne_boxSet] = useState(false);
const [mealTwo_box, mealTwo_boxSet] = useState(false);
const [mealThree_box, mealThree_boxSet] = useState(false);
const [mealFour_box, mealFour_boxSet] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {     
    const user = Authentication.auth().currentUser;
    {
        user !== null &&
            Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .get()
                .then(doc => {
                    healthDataSet(doc.data())
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error reading health", error);
                });
    }
}, []);  
    {
        healthData.gender === 'female' ?
            BMRset(655.1 + (9.563 * healthData.weight) + (1.850 * healthData.height) - (4.676 * healthData.age))
            :
            BMRset(88.2 + (13.362 * healthData.weight) + (4.799 * healthData.height) - (5.677 * healthData.age))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is you are not properly waiting for an async call to return. A render will be called before the async is complete, so you need to prepare for this case. I would suggest adding a loading state:

```js
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true)
  const [ healthData, setHealthData ] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        setHealthData(doc.data())
        setLoading(false)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error reading health", error);
      });
  }, [])
  
  if (loading || healthData == null) return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
  return healthData.gender === 'female' ?
    <MyStuff /> :
    <MyOtherStuff />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I understand the premise of the loader as it gets switched to false upon triggering I'm a bit confused about the async as I've never used it how would I specifically implement that to the database code I have?

Comment: Updated my answer to use your call in your post. Pretty much when the setHealthData is called (because the data has returned from the database/api) then you can set the loading to false since you are no longer loading/waiting on the data to be populated.